# SharePoint Foundation 2013 One Page Responsive Design

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm setting up a travel site that includes big pictures (1600px wide). Site looks good on the big screen but obviously being out-of-the box means it isn't responsive. I googled some ways around this but have not came across anything really reliable. It also only needs to be this page right now so I don't want to make too many changes to the master pages. Is there a way around this, or should I come up with a new design that doesn't use big pictures? I can show a screenshot of my site if needed.

Comment: maybe this soultion could help you some how : https://gallerifficapp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add css with media queries to your pages to make the images on your site responsive. For example:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
        size: 600px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would solve this problem to add new site (or change current one) for this type of pic's and use it wide layout (change masterpage) for it which will be accurate for wide pics. Its possible to play with CSS of SharePoint to get accurate as needed too.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your answer. Anyway you could provide an example? I played with the bootstrap add on found on codeplex, but after setting it up, it still wasn't shrinking images down like it should.